# Keep template files organised when using a front-end + backend framework

Tags: templates, directory-structure

I'm using Angular and Mojolicious (Perl) for an app and was wondering if there's a way to keep all my html and TT (a template engine for Perl) templates outside of the public directory? Currently I'm placing my html templates under the public directory and my TT templates live elsewhere.

Ideally I would like to have my html templates under the same folder as my TT templates but they aren't accessible with my JS files when using Angular directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this [using Mojolicious::Static](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Static):

```
push @{$static->paths}, '/directory/path';
```